# Total sales, MTD sales per date

Tags: sql-server

Need to show total sales for each date between Jun 13th 2019 - Jun 27th 2019, along with MTD sales for each date (Jun 1st 2019 - current date).

This is my query:

```
select date, sum(sales) as 'Daily Sales', 
sum(sales) over (partition by datepart(month, date) order by date ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) as 'MTD Sales' 
from Orders 
where date between '13/06/2019' and '27/06/2019'
group by date;
```

Upon adding the `where` clause, it changes the MTD sales to show the running total starting only from the 13th, when I want the MTD running total to start from the 1st.

This is the output desired:

```
Date    | Daily Sales | MTD Sales
---------------------------------
13 June | 200         | 700
15 June | 300         | 1000
20 June | 500         | 1500
```

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried to use some SQL to achieve this? If yes, what was it and how did it fail to achieve your requirement?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have done so far? 


Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the window function calculated *after* the `where` clause is evaluated, you have to execute this as two queries. Here's an example:

```
;with [MTD sales] as (
    select date, sum(sales) as 'Daily Sales', 
    sum(sales) over (partition by datepart(month, date) order by date ROWS between unbounded preceding and current row) as 'MTD Sales' 
    from Orders 
    group by date;
)
select *
from [MTD sales]
where date between '13/06/2019' and '27/06/2019'
```

This uses a CTE to run calculate the correct to date sum, and then applies the filtering as a second step after the correct calculations have been run.

Comment: This is such a perfectly elegant solution! I can't believe I did not think of this! Thank you!